# A confuse about final keyword used in ActivityThread

Tags: java, android, final

As the source of the ActivityThread class shows, it's a `final` class, and all the methods in this class is also `final`  methods. As the `final`  keyword definition in java, this class cannot be inherited, but why android developers keep those methods `final` ?

Maybe I didn't express the question clear, I fix it here.

ActivityThread is a `final`  class, it will not have any sub-class, and no method will be overridden, but you know that all the methods in this class is `final` , I want to know why they need these `final`  keywords, they can remove them with no impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2) makes it clear that no method of a `final` class can be overridden. Thus, the `final` declaration on the methods appear to be redundant. (Maybe left over from a beta version of the Android API when ActivityThread was perhaps not a final class?)

On the other hand, optimizers and obfuscators can sometimes do a little more with methods declared `final`. Although they ought to be smart enough to make the inference that a final class won't have any overridden methods, it can't hurt to give them the extra hint.

Answer (score 1):

> > why android developers keep those methods final?

Actually, the Java engineers did that. It's a design decision: sometimes you want to prohibit sub-classing one of your classes. Why? Some of the reason is that it implies some strong responsibility, that forces you to take very smart decisions.

Let me reference part of the item number 17 of [Effective Java Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) by *Joshua Bloch*:

> > So what does it mean for a class to be designed and documented for inheritance?
> >     First, the class must document precisely the effects of overriding any method. In other words, the class must document its self-use of overridable methods. For each public or protected method or constructor, the documentation must indicate which overridable methods the method or constructor invokes, in what sequence, and how the results of each invocation affect subsequent processing. (By overridable, we mean nonfinal and either public or protected.) More generally, a class must document any circumstances under which it might invoke an overridable method. For example, invocations might come from background threads or static initializers.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > Design for inheritance involves more than just documenting patterns of self- use. To allow programmers to write efficient subclasses without undue pain, a class may have to provide hooks into its internal workings in the form of judi- ciously chosen protected methods or, in rare instances, protected fields.

Comment: but I think there's no need to keep these final keywords for ActivityThread's methods. the final of the class has done the work that prohibit itself and its methods to be inherited or overridden.

Comment: Now I got your point. You are right, final keyword for methods are unnecessary in that case. Good catch!

Comment: I must disagree about the reference to the Java engineers. Lots of final classes in the java packages (such as java.lang.String) have none of their methods declared final. This was the work of the Android development team. Also, this post is not responsive to OP's question, which asked why a final class should have any methods declared final.